# NuxtJS: Disable link if id is undefined or empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

```
<nuxt-link :to="{
  name: 'player-id',
  params: {
    id: nickname
  }
}">{{ username }}</nuxt-link>
```

How could I disable the nuxt link above if nickname is undefined or empty like ""?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<router-link>` or `<nuxt-link>` is rendered with `<a>` by default ([Refer to Vue Router Guide](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link)), `<a>` doesn't have attr=`disabled` exists in `<button>`.

One solution is binds props=`to` like `nickname ? next-route : ''`, and uses same way to toggle your own `disabled` classes/styles.

```
<nuxt-link :to="nickname ? {
  name: 'player-id',
  params: {
    id: nickname
  }
} : ''">{{ username }}</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's turned out you cannot add `disabled` attr to nuxt-link, you need to fake `disabled` state with css.

```
<nuxt-link :to="{
  name: 'player-id',
  params: {
    id: nickname
  }}"
  :class="{'disabled-link': !nickname}"
  >{{ username }}</nuxt-link>
```

In your styles:

```
 .disabled-link {
   color: grey;
   cursor-pointer: none;
 }
```

Also I'd suggest you to remove your route object to computed properties not to clutter the template:

```
 <nuxt-link :to="userPath"
  :class="{'disabled-link': !nickname}"
  >{{ username }}</nuxt-link>

computed: {
userPath() {
 return {
  name: 'player-id',
  params: {
    id: this.nickname
  }}
}
}
```

Comment: this only works if `nuxt-link` is rendered with tag=`<button>` instead of `<a>`

Comment: You mean you can't set `disbled` attr to `<a>`?  I've tested it, works for Chrome

Comment: check [this simple demo in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-frog-vxhn8?file=/pages/index.vue), and I don't see `<a>` has attr=`disabled` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Interesting. Well, in my defence, check this out:) 
https://codepen.io/DavidGolodetsky/pen/BaKvzEb

Comment: So yeah, you're right my answer doesn't work with nuxt-link. In this case you need to bind a css class which would fake disabled state. I'll correct that. But it's funny why it's working with plain `a`

Comment: your codepen example applied css properties from `quasar` framework. if remove `quasar.min.css` from your codepen, then you will find disable not working any more.

Comment: oh, man:) totally... I tested this in a codepen that was used for another thing with Quasar. You're totally right!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-if` , `v-else` to render nuxt-link or just a text

```
<nuxt-link v-if="nickname"
  :to="{
  name: 'player-id',
  params: {
    id: nickname
  }
}">{{ username }}</nuxt-link>
<i v-else>{{ username }}</i>
```